# Remove the version text from the Welcome screen

Tags: inno-setup

On Welcome screen i get this message

> This will install "My Program Name" version 1.0 on your computer

How i can remove this `version 1.0`. I want it to be just:

> This will install "My Program Name" on your computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text there uses the value of the `AppVerName` directive which defaults to "AppName version AppVersion".

If you want to override to to show just the AppName, you can use the same value as the AppName directive:

```
AppName=My Program Name
AppVersion=1.0
AppVerName=My Program Name
```